# Method name containing a dash?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I create a method that contains a dash in the name?

```
public void my-method-name()
{
}
```

Comment: By changing programming language. Use Lisp, for instance.

Comment: To use with ASP.NET MVC actions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Use [ActionNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameattribute.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. It violate the identifier specification. But you can put other Unicode character set. e.g you can give a function name.

```
void 中國話 (int i){
}
```

in .NET and you can use _ underscore instead of -.